# setState does not work after restart in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-oauth

I am working with an app in flutter that does google authentication for a project, but it isn't working as intended.
It works by first going to a Root widget that will check if the user is already signed in, and if they are they will be sent to a home page. And if they aren't they will be sent to a login page.
The logic works perfect on a first run. That being when I run it for the first time after having just installed the App, or after uninstalling and installing it again. But it does not work after I restart it, or if I run it again after stopping the debugging.
I am not sure what the problem is, but it seems like the setState isn't calling the build again after it is built for the first time. And the check for if a user is logged in is over.

```
import 'package:finfacil/states/current_user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../home/home.dart';
import '../login/login.dart';

enum AuthStatus {
  notLoggedIn,
  loggedIn,
}

class Root extends StatefulWidget {
  const Root({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Root> createState() => _RootState();
}

class _RootState extends State<Root> {
  AuthStatus _authStatus = AuthStatus.notLoggedIn;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    CurrentUser currentUser = Provider.of<CurrentUser>(context, listen: false);
    String returnString = await currentUser.onStartUp();

    if (returnString == "success") {
      setState(() {
        _authStatus = AuthStatus.loggedIn;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _authStatus = AuthStatus.notLoggedIn;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget retVal = Container();

    switch (_authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.notLoggedIn:
        retVal = Login();
        break;
      case AuthStatus.loggedIn:
        retVal = Home();
        break;
      default:
    }

    return retVal;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your onStartUp logic? Apparently you return sucess after the app has been started once

Comment: Please log any errors or messages from when it doesn't startup.